# Css how to replace block after click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My requirement is that..I have a **box**. inside **box** I have a **form**..What I want is that..When I click the **submit button** ,inside the **box** the form will gone and a message will display.
Just like this:
[image]

```
I have the jefiddle :
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qyj62dv/)

here ,When I click to the submit button,message is appearing on the top and the box1 is going down..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this**

HTML: (Change **type= submit to type=button**)

```
<input type="button" name="create" class="enter submit" value="Enter"  onclick="showDiv()" >
```

CSS: (Change **type= submit to type=button**)

```
.box2 input[type=button] {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.answer_list{
    margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
    background:pink;
   height:300px;
    width:400px;
  display: block;
  border: dotted;
  border-width: 1px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0qyj62dv/3/)

Answer (score 2):

I'd much prefer using jQuery to do this, but here's the updated fiddle using only javascript, and keeping changes minimal.

```
<div id="box">
  <div class="box2">
      <h1 id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >welcome</h1>
      <h1 id="details">Details</h1>
      <form id="foo-form" method="POST" onsubmit="return showDiv();">
          <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Your name"/>
          <input type="submit" name="create" class="enter submit" value="Enter"/>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

... and the script ...

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('details').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('foo-form').style.display = "none";
   return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0qyj62dv/7/

The form elements are now being hidden, the original details message is being hidden, and the welcome text is within the box now, not external to it. Oh, and I moved the function call to onsubmit of the form, so it returns false now and doesn't actually try to submit the form on jsfiddle.

Hth

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with same styling as that of `#box`.

Let's say `answer_box`

```
.answer_box {
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    border: dotted;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

Add `answer_box` class to welcome container.

```
<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_box" ><h1> WELCOME<h1></div>
```

To align it from top, give little `margin` to `<h1>` inside welcome div.

You need to hide the box container when submit is clicked.

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('box').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: I need to put the message inside the box..like the picture.Please look at the picture

Answer (score 0):

look at this example,
http://jsfiddle.net/0qyj62dv/8/

all you need to do is this

1. submit form using ajax.
2. Add the welcome tab and form tab inside same parent div
3. toggle tabs as you want using style.display property

   ```
   <button type="button" name="create" class="enter submit" onclick="submitForm()">Enter</button>


   function submitForm(){

   document.getElementById('tab2').style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = "none";
       $.ajax({
           method: 'POST',
           url : '',
           data : $('#myForm').serialize(),
           success : function(data){
               console.log('success',data);
               alert('success');
           }
       });
   }
   ```

you may call this using jquery